# Diffie-Hellman -- Primitive root mod n -- cryptography question

Tags: vector, root, primitive, diffie-hellman

In the below snippet, please explain starting with the first "for" loop what is happening and why. Why is 0 added, why is 1 added in the second loop. What is going on in the "if" statement under bigi. Finally explain the modPow method. Thank you in advance for meaningful replies.

```
public static boolean isPrimitive(BigInteger m, BigInteger n) {

    BigInteger bigi, vectorint;
    Vector<BigInteger> v = new Vector<BigInteger>(m.intValue());
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<m.intValue();i++)
        v.add(new BigInteger("0"));

    for (i=1;i<m.intValue();i++)
    {
        bigi = new BigInteger("" + i);

        if (m.gcd(bigi).intValue() == 1)
            v.setElementAt(new BigInteger("1"), n.modPow(bigi,m).intValue());
    }

    for (i=0;i<m.intValue();i++)
    {
        bigi = new BigInteger("" + i);

        if (m.gcd(bigi).intValue() == 1)
        {
            vectorint = v.elementAt(bigi.intValue());
            if ( vectorint.intValue() == 0)
                i = m.intValue() + 1;
        }
    }

    if (i == m.intValue() + 2)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Comment: this is clearly homework. My question is: why people tend not even to change the text of their question to seem somewhat different from a typical homework question? "Finally explain the modPow method.".. this makes me lol.

Answer (score 1):

- Treat the vector as a list of booleans, with one boolean for each number 0 to m.  When you view it that way, it becomes obvious that each value is set to 0 to initialize it to false, and then set to 1 later to set it to true.
- The last for loop is testing all the booleans.  If any of them are 0 (indicating false), then the function returns false.  If all are true, then the function returns true.
- Explaining the `if` statement you asked about would require explaining what a primitive root mod n is, which is the whole point of the function.  I think if your goal is to understand this program, you should first understand what it implements.  If you read [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) on it, you'll see this in the first paragraph:

> In modular arithmetic, a branch of
>   number theory, a primitive root modulo
>   n is any number g with the property
>   that any number coprime to n is
>   congruent to a power of g (mod n).
>   That is, if g is a primitive root (mod
>   n), then for every integer a that has
>   gcd(a, n) = 1, there is an integer k
>   such that gk ≡ a (mod n). k is called
>   the index of a. That is, g is a
>   generator of the multiplicative group
>   of integers modulo n.

- The function [modPow](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) implements [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).  Once you understand how to find a primitive root mod n, you'll understand it.

Perhaps the final piece of the puzzle for you is to know that two numbers are *coprime* if their greatest common divisor is 1.  And so you see these checks in the algorithm you pasted.

Bonus link:  [This paper](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/coding/Overheads/11_sunze_proots.pdf) has some nice background, including how to test for primitive roots near the end.